# Fixing MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query, please check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8102d/1

**My expected result is like this:**

```
PartID           |IdMesin|MR|MOSGN|NOP|MT|MS|MOSTRO|NF |MORREST|MOR |NJ|TRY |
AWDX-FG001-HC-KGX|BH 260K|0 |   0 | 0 |0 |0 |0     |600|0      |1200|0 |9000|
AWDX-FG001-HC-KGX|BH 260Q|0 |   0 | 0 |0 |0 |0     |0  |0      |0   |0 |3600|
AWDX-FG002-HN-KGX|BH 260K|3600|0  | 0 |0 |0 |0     |0  |0      |0   |0 |0   |
BLAP-FG100-GS-KGX|BS 80F |0 | 0  |3600| 0|0 |0     |0  |0      |0   | 0|0   |
EIXX-FG000-MX-KGX|BS 80F |0 | 0  |  0 |0 |0 |0  |1800  |0      |0   |0 |0   | 
HMXX-FG330-XX-KGX|BS 320E|0 |0    |0  |0 |0 |3600  |0  |0      |0   |0 |0   |
MCMX-FG638-PX-KGX|SM 120F|0 |3600 |0  |0 |0 |0     |0  |0      |0   |0 |0   |
```

I hope you can help me to solve it, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need conditional aggregation rather than a bunch of ifs.

Comment: @P.Salmon can you write the query what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation there are lots of examples in SO and elsewhere and here's another -

```
SELECT
    PartID,
    IdMesin,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'MR001' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,   0)) ELSE 0 END) AS MR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'MOSGN01' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0, 0)) ELSE 0 END) AS MOSGN,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'NO001' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,   0)) ELSE 0 END) AS NOP,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'MT001' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,   0)) ELSE 0 END) AS MT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'MOS01' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,   0)) ELSE 0 END) AS MS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'MOSTR01' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0, 0)) ELSE 0 END) AS MOSTRO,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'NF001' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,   0)) ELSE 0 END) AS NF,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'MOSR01' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,  0)) ELSE 0 END) AS MORREST,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'MOR01' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,   0)) ELSE 0 END) AS MOR,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'NJ001' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,   0)) ELSE 0 END) AS NJ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN IdDowntime = 'TRY01' THEN TIME_TO_SEC(maketime(durasi + 0,substring_index(durasi, 'Jam ', - 1) + 0,   0)) ELSE 0 END) AS TRY
FROM    trans_lhpdtdw
WHERE DivisiId = 'IJ001' AND Tanggal = '2017-10-02'
GROUP BY    PartID, IdMesin
ORDER BY PartID
```

Comment: this is subquery , when i join in main query, the result multiplied by two. I join with same partid and same idmesin. here is my main query, check this out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/616e96/1

Comment: That's scope creep I'm out.